# How to export the contents of nodes in a view

Tags: views

I have a view that displays content based on some criteria. I would like to export all of the content of the results of the view into a text document or Excel spreadsheet, as I am intending to edit them for a book. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take look at these modules:
[Views Data Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export),
[Views Excel Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_export_xls)

Here is screencast about *Views Data Export*

http://www.lullabot.com/articles/module-monday-views-data-export

Answer (score 1):

The module I use for this is http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export

You create a new style and attach it to your existing page/pane, you can export:

- CSV
- Microsoft XLS
- Microsoft DOC
- Basic TXT
- XML